# Как отследить изменение текста внутри элемента?

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется такой код, текст которого меняется динамически:

```
<ul id="color-values">
    <li><label>HEX:</label><span id="hex">#FF0000</span></li>
</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне отследить событие с помощью javascript, которое вызывается когда содержимое текста меняется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так )

```js
const hex = document.getElementById('hex');

hex.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', () => {
  console.log('change');
})

function changeColor() {
  hex.textContent = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}
```

```css
#hex {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul id="color-values">
  <li><label>HEX:</label><span id="hex">#FF0000</span></li>
</ul>

<button onclick="changeColor()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает

Comment: `DOMSubtreeModified` - устаревший метод, вместо него используйте аналог в виде `MutationObserver` более современный и быстрый.

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно для отслеживания использовать **MutationObserver**, **DOMSubtreeModified**. Но зачем вообще отслеживать? Не проще ли событие по изменению содержимого повесить на то же самое событие, которое и вызывает это изменение? Т. е., другими словами, переписать функцию **changeColor()** таким образом:

```js
function changeColor() {
  hex.textContent = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  console.log('change');
}
```

И без лишней заморочки.

Ещё не забываем, что **toString(16)** не приводит к корректному переводу из десятичной в шестнадцатеричную системы для задавания цвета, так как если код составляющей цвета получается меньшим, чем hex 10, то нужно впереди дописывать "0".